# Saving a constantly changing score in an android app

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android app in java, the score in the game changes all the time, multiple times every second. I want to create a save file to be able to keep track of the score when the user comes back to the app, the thing is how should I go about saving it? Seems extremely inefficient to write to the save file multiple times every second whenever the score changes. I thought about saving it in the onDestroy() method, but I heard it's not guaranteed that it would be called...

So what would be a guaranteed way for the score to be saved while not having to access file multiple times every second?

Comment: Push your scores onto an in-memory queue and write the batch to your file every so often (i.e. once every five seconds), or defer them to `onPause`, which will always been called unless the app crashes

Comment: Is onPause guaranteed to be called in all other cases? Say the phone is turned off while in the app, will it be called?

Comment: Except for your app crashing or some other exceptional, unforseeable circumstance, then yes - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458770/is-onpause-guaranteed-to-be-called-when-an-activity-is-no-longer-running)

Comment: You can save the score in persistent data storage like `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: use the solution suggested by @ShubhamPanchal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a SharedPreferences used to store data that belong to an app.

> To add value to the SharedPreferences

```
//Whenever you update the score call this function
void updateScore(int score){

    SharedPreferences mySharedPref = getSharedPreferences("give Any Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("score", score);
    editor.apply();  //this function will commit asynchronously

}
```

If you need to get the score at any time call this function.

```
//Whenever you update the score call this function
public int getScore(){

    SharedPreferences mySharedPref = getSharedPreferences("give Any Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return mySharedPref.getInt("score", -1); //-1 is the default value that is returned if the value is not set using putInt

}
```